How to combine divisions and fractions?
On my Facebook-account, regularly I see questions about calculations, like $1 \div \frac{1}{2}$, which makes me doubt if this equals $0.5$ or $2$.
I remember from my childhood that such notation was forbidden: you either use divisions ($1 \div 1 \div 2$, which equals $0.5$) or fractions ($\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}$, which equals $2$), but never the combination of both.
What is the official agreement on this? Is my childhood correct? :-)

I don't think the notation is ambiguous.  When $b\neq 0 $, the equation $a\div b = c$ is equivalent to $a=b\times c $.  Here, $1=\frac 12\times 2$ so $1\div \frac 12= 2$.  By contrast, $a\div b\div c$ is terrible notation, since $\div$ is non-associative.

I have no problem if somebody downvotes my questions or answers, as long as you EXPLAIN WHY so that I can take your question into account!

The expression 1÷(1/2) is different from 1÷1÷2 because of how it was written. The first expression is 1 divided by the quotient of 1 and 2, while the second expression is the quotient of 1 and 1 being divided by 2. Also, we use fractions to represent a number in a way which does not need decimal point. An example of this is 0.5 which can be expressed as 1/2. I hope this clears your confusion.

So, in your opinion, the notation $1 \div \frac{1}{2}$ is correct and it means the same as $1 \div (\frac{1}{2})$? (This would mean that the fraction operator goes before the division operator, which is quite weird because they have the same meaning.)

Sorry for my confusing answer, what I meant was you can use both operators at the same time. It just depends on what was needed. And yes, the fraction operator goes first before the operator. Fractions are representations of another number. Meaning you can use it like a variable. For example: a = (1/2); 1 ÷ a = 1 ÷ (1/2).

@Dominique Yes, the fraction bar also works as a grouping operator. Just like $\sqrt{\qquad}$, anything "contained" by it is automatically grouped together, and so it gets higher precedence

@Dominique $1 \div \frac{1}{2}$ would mean that the fraction operator goes before the division operator, which is quite weird because they have the same meaning. $\quad$ It is irrelevant that division and fraction mean the same; the point is that as written, the fraction asks to be dealt with before that main division, that is, there are implicit parentheses around the fraction. $\quad$ If $10\div5^{-1}$ doesn't equal half, why should $1 \div \frac{1}{2}$ equal half?

$10 \div 5^{-1}$ equals $50$ because of the priority of the operations: first powers and roots, then multiplications and divisions, and finally additions and subtractions. $1 \div \frac{1}{2}$ can be written as $1 \div 1 \div 2$ (as $\frac{1}{2}$ indeed equals $1 \div 2$. I admit, writing divisions like this is very bad because of the division not being associative. ... which, for me, is a direct reason to strictly enforce the usage of brackets while dividing by fractions, just in order to enforce clarity.
